# Type error: Too few arguments to function laravel 5.4

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I'm having an html href where I want to pass values to a controller method but it displays `Type error: Too few arguments to function`

## HTML

```
<li><a href="{{route('sidebarSearch.show',['type'=>$all,'title'=>$title])}}">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> all</a></li>
<li><a href="{{route('sidebarSearch.show',['type'=>$paid,'title'=>$title])}}">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> paid</a></li>
<li><a href="{{route('sidebarSearch.show',['type'=>$free,'title'=>$title])}}">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> free</a></li>
```

## controller

```
public function show($type,$title)
{


  //
}`
```

Comment: I guess you are sending an array and it takes on $type, thats the reazon Too few arguments, try to delete $title variable.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing the variable in the route declaration. Check the route name in your routes file to see it the code looks like that:

```
Route::get('/sidebarSearch/show/{type}/{title}', 'SidebarSearchController@show')->name('sidebarSearch.show');
```

Also run a `php artisan route:cache` and then `php artisan route:list` to check if the name column has a sidebarSearch.show declared with the right parameters.

If in your case you are referring to the show method of a resource (index, create, store, update, show etc) you can overrite the method by only adding the route above to your route files.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was basically to use [link_to_route()](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#paths) or [link_to_action()](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#paths) and pass the parameters .